# Riemann-Stieltjes proof problem

Tags: integration

$\int _a^bf(x)g(x)dx$ = $\int _a^bf(x)dG(x)dx$

$\int _a^bf(x)dG(x)dx$   $\iff$  $\exists$  $\int_a^b f(x)dG_1(x)$

Could someone explain this thing?

Comment: Your second line has a number, not a statement, on the left of $\iff$ , so it makes no sense.

Comment: How do you mean a number?

Comment: I mean a real number (assuming that your functions are real-valued).  The value of an integral is a number, not a statement, but $\iff$ makes sense only between statements.

Comment: Aha, I understand, but the problem is that is is a problem given to me by my professor, and he told the whole class that he doubts anyone will solve it.

Comment: Do you maybe know if this can be proven?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216242/proof-for-two-riemann-stieltjes-integrals